# Where is \doturn documented?

Tags: rotating

This seems to be obliquely referred to in the `latextutor` pdf but only in a code fragment taken out of context:

```
$x_1$ \doturn{\fbox{Bad thing}}\\
$x_2$ \doturn{\raisebox{\depth}\\
{\fbox{Bad thing}}}\\
$x_3$ \doturn{\raisebox{-\height}\\
{\fbox{Bad thing}}} $x_4$
```

Apparently `\doturn` here, even in an example program with these packages included:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Miktex console doesn't show the rotating package any more, presumably because it has been moved into the graphics bundle. Can any of you give me a minimum example `tex` file that will illustrate the usage of the `\doturn` command?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! it seems that this command is not defined in any package but in some document as `\newcommand ...`.

Comment: A search for `\doturn` in the whole `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/` tree yields no match.

Comment: A search for `\doturn` on the site yields no match. It's really impossible to say more.

Comment: Rotating is still there, as it is the source of sidewaysfigure and landscape (see also pdflscape).  \rotatebox is part of the graphics package.

Answer (score 3):

The `\doturn` command is defined in the `ltxprimer` document you reference. The source code seems to be available as [`ltxprimer-src-1.0.tar.gz`](http://sarovar.org/frs/download.php/121/ltxprimer-src-1.0.tar.gz) but the server doesn't respond to me. I found an older version of that tutorial on the [Indian TeX Users Group's site](http://tug.org/tutorials/tugindia/src/) which defines `\doturn` in [`chap05.tex`](http://tug.org/tutorials/tugindia/src/chap05.tex) simply as:

```
\def\doturn#1{\rotatebox{45}{#1}}
```

Here are the relevant parts of the tutorial to reproduce the example with the rotated boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\def\doturn#1{\rotatebox{45}{#1}}

$x_1$ \doturn{\fbox{Bad thing}}
$x_2$ \doturn{\raisebox{\depth}{\fbox{Bad thing}}}
$x_3$ \doturn{\raisebox{-\height}{\fbox{Bad thing}}}
$x_4$
\end{document}
```

[image]